# How to prove that $\operatorname{span} S=S$ iff $S$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

S is a subspace of V $\leftrightarrow$ span(S) = S

Concerning this theorem, how can I prove it?
Can you give me some hint?

Comment: How the $S$ is defined ? What is it ?

Comment: I have used the `proof-verification` tag. *Which* proof do you want us to verify?

Comment: Probably you should include your definition of $\operatorname{span} S$. Did you learn a theorem that $\operatorname{span} M$ is a subpsace for any *subset* $M$? Did you learn that you always have $M\subseteq \operatorname{span} M$?

Comment: Try to prove the two inclusions.  Show that $S\subseteq \text {Span}(S)$ and conversely.

Comment: You could also have a look at some older posts to see whether they help you. For example: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1609596
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358069
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1973226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any subset $S$ of a $K$-vector space $V$, the span of $S$ contains $S$.

Conversely, if $S$ is a subspace of $V$, each element of the span of $S$ is contained in $S$, since $S$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Thus the span of $S$ is contained in $S$. Done.

Note that the span of $S$ consists of all linear combinations $a_1s_1 + \ldots + a_ns_n$, where $n\geq 0$, $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in K$, and $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S$.